# Ubuntu Server/PHP: How do I ensure WP uses the latest PHP version on my server?

Tags: php

I have just installed PHP 7.3.8 on our server:

```
> /var/www/html# which php
#=> /usr/bin/php
```

```
> php -v
#=> PHP 7.3.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2019 09:52:12) ( NTS )...
```

I've restarted the server and logged in and out of WP. However, WP is still running PHP 7.2.

How do I ensure WP runs on the latest PHP version?

Comment: Can you post your webserver and virtualhost config pls?

Comment: Where do I find those?